# Are these passive sentences correct?

Tags: passive

Do these passive sentences make sense or are they wrong?

> Mir wird nichts gesagt. – I’m not being talked to; nothing is being said to me.
>
> Bei den Kino wird geraucht, obwohl man es nicht darf. – At the cinema lots of people smoke, despite the fact that you can not.
>
> Es werden heute viele Kleidung aus Wolle gemacht. – Lots of clothes are made of wool today.

**Edit:** It has been said in comments that there are several mistakes in these sentences. Do these mistakes relate to the use of "passive" construction, or to other matters.

Comment: Please ask more specific questions.

Comment: No, there are several mistakes.

Comment: I (hopefully) clarified the question by specifying the mistakes as relating or not relating to the "passive" construction, and wonder if the question can't be re-opened in its current form.

Comment: @TomAu I appreciate your efforts into improving these questions. For that reason I voted for open, although I'm still seeing some critical issues. Anyways, I'd rather like to see that OP's themselves improve their question. It's not our job to make their questions good; I mean, to guess what their problem is.

Comment: @Em1: This is a totally new user (rep=1)  who asked a fairly detailed question (for a "newbie"), but who couldn't come up with a good punch line to finish the query. I, an "intermediate" user, am just good enough to do this, and am trying to "lead by example."

Comment: @TomAu Fair enough. I really appreciate your effort. The point I'm seeing is that the question still is a little, um, broad. There's no *real* question in it; and what I'm missing is a response to the comment of Carsten Schultz; at least asking what he(actually we all) mean by being more specific. Anyway. I didn't intend to discuss this here much further. And I clearly do not want to keep you from editing. It's surely a benefit to this site.

Comment: Ok, I vote reopen, altough I'm not sure how this question would be useful to other users/visitors. However I'll correct the mistakes that don't concern the passive voice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Mir wird nichts gesagt" is ok.

At first sight, the second should be "Beim Kino wird geraucht, obwohl man es nicht kann." But I assume you mean "obwohl man es nicht darf" (i.e. although it is forbidden). And if "at the cinema" means *inside* the building (while watching films) and not literally *standing outside but near the building', then it should be "Im Kino wird viel geraucht, obwohl man es nicht darf."

Kleidung is always singular. Thus "Es wird heute viel Kleidung (or: viele textilien) aus Wolle gemacht". Maybe "Heute wird ..." instead of "Es wird heute ..."

Comment: Thanks - bei den was a typo: i meant bei dem, but could have put beim. Also I meant outside the cinema: the area around

Comment: @user3476093 Smoking bans outside the cinema?! Never heard of...

Answer (score 2):

- Mir wird nichts gesagt: Absolutely correct.
- Bei den Kino wird geraucht, trotzdem man nicht kann:

  - First, "Bei den Kino" is grammatically wrong; it should be "Bei dem Kino" or simply "Beim Kino".
  - I *think* with "at the cinema" you mean inside; unlike the English "at", the German "bei" does not include that. The German "beim Kino" excludes to be inside it, it means "close to the cinema". So if you mean that the people smoke e.g. in front of the door, then "beim Kino" is right, but if you mean they smoke inside, you have to say "im Kino".
  - Instead of "trotzdem", you have to use "obwohl" or "trotz der Tatsache, dass" here.
  - It should be "obwohl man *es* nicht kann".
  - While "obwohl man es nicht kann" is a correct translation of "despite the fact you cannot", it doesn't make sense to me in either language. If you cannot smoke there, it is impossible that you smoke there. I guess you meant "despite the fact that you are not allowed to" which would be translated as "obwohl man es nicht darf."
- Es werden heute viele Kleidung aus Woole gemacht:

  - "Kleidung" is singular, therefore "Es *wird* heute viel Kleidung ... gemacht". Alternatively you can use the plural word "Kleider": "Es werden heute viele Kleider ... gemacht"
  - The German word for wool is "Wolle", not "Woole"
  - While "Kleidung machen" is not exactly wrong, it is not the best German. You should prefer "Kleidung herstellen" (to produce clothes). Therefore you would say "Es wird heute viel Kleidung aus Wolle hergestellt."